Environment variable set through direnv not passed to go debugging session on vscode
I have set direnv to export an API key:
$ cat .envrc
export API_KEY=XXX

This key is available in my terminal:
$ echo $API_KEY
XXX

In my go project, I'm reading the environment variable to grab the API key: os.GetEnv("API_KEY")
As soon as I try to debug the code in VSCode, the environment variable is just not set:
b64_encoded_api_key := os.Getenv("API_KEY")
fmt.Printf("b64_encoded_api_key: -->%v<--\n", b64_encoded_api_key)

Starting: /Users/.../golang/1.23.1/packages/bin/dlv dap --listen=127.0.0.1:65079 --log-dest=3 from /Users/...
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:65079
Type 'dlv help' for list of commands.
b64_encoded_api_key: --><--

Then I tried to update the launch.json file to include the environment variable:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Package",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": "${fileDirname}",
      "env": {
        "API_KEY": "${env:API_KEY}",
      }
    }
  ]
}

But the result stays the same.
Is there a way I can get the environment variable set in this directory (through direnv) to be set in the debugging environment?

I managed to sort this out by:

update the file ~/.config/direnv/direnv.toml
add load_dotenv = true in the [global]section (see https://direnv.net/man/direnv.toml.1.html#global)

deleting the .envrc file from my workspace folder
both .envrc and .env can't be loaded together by direnv. Only the .envrc file will be loaded if both files exist

create a .env file with the content API_KEY=xxx in my workspace folder

add the configuration item "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" to the configuration in the launch.json


